# How do I remove these errors that can't be deleted?

Tags: windows-error-reporting

I received a call from "Microsoft Tech Support" people saying they've received over 500 error messages from my computer in the last three days, and after some over the phone step-by-step instructions, I was led to this screen:

[image]

I discovered that there are 17,686 errors and 900 some odd warnings that can't be deleted. I was told by the tech support guy that I need a program called PC Matic to be able to delete these errors, and of course I could buy it from him, but I have NO money at all to spend on fixing this computer. Researching the program a little, I found YouTube videos claiming that it's a scam. I could use any help I can get. Can I use a program to fix this problem, or am I looking at completely re-formating?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Don't worry about those errors, they are normal.  Seriously there is NO problem with your computer.  The phone-call you got is a scam.  Microsoft does *not* go around phoning random people.  If you want actual help from Microsoft you go to them and you pay them for a support contract.  Other than that you don't exist to them.  The scam part of the phone call is the software they want you to buy and install.  The software is not needed - the error log is *normal* and if you fall for the scam and buy the software then no doubt in addition to taking your money the software will install malware.

Short answer: it's a scam.  Don't worry about the errors - they are *normal*, just go back to using your computer as normal.

Comment: I agree with @Bill and I would go as far as ensuring that there isn't malware on the computer sending your personal information to the people who called you.

Comment: I know it's a scam.  Where I live the scammers have been trying this for a while now.  We have a regional radio talk-show and people call in asking about these phone-calls.  The answer, as put together by many people, is that it is a scam.  Plain and simple, scam.

Comment: The only problem with that is they said told me they had received all the error messages in the last three day's... Well, my computer is running just fine, except for when I try and play ANY of my games... It freezes up at random, so far on 4 different games, and this problem ALSO started sometime in the last 3 or 4 day's... Is this a coincidence, or could it be related??

Comment: It is certainly a coincidence.  The phone call is definitely a scam: Microsoft *will not* call you for any reason.  Because that person was misrepresenting themselves as Microsoft you know that the call was not legitimate.  Scam.  Your issues with games, like you say, is just a coincidence.  See if you can get a knowledgeable friend to come over and help.

Comment: @Skatr It's coincidence. It reminds me of a story of a man who received an "illegal operation" error on his computer, and then heard the sound of a police car with the siren on driving past his house. He was sure they were coming for him. ;D